# Looping through a checkbox array that has one element

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox

I have a list of dynamically created checkboxes named "tags" which I loop through with javascript to make sure only 1 is checked and to get the value. If for some reason this list of checkboxes only has 1 item, my script won't look at it. When I alert the tag's length I get undefined.

```
    var total=[];
    for (var i=0; i < document.form1.tags.length; i++){
        if(document.form1.tags[i].checked==true){
            total.push(document.form1.tags[i].value);
        }
    }

    if(total.length==0){
        alert("Please select a product to edit.");
    }else if (total.length>1){
        alert("Please select only one product to edit.");
    }else{
        document.location = "go somewhere";
    }
```

Comment: `.tags` is not an array when there is only one checkbox, it contains direct reference to the one checkbox. It only becomes a nodelist when there are more than one checkboxes with the same name. You should always look at the developer console and you would have seen the error there.

Comment: @Esailija Yet another reason to use `querySelectorAll` or jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. use `getElementsByName` instead to get all the elements so you can iterate them:
2. Use a framework like jquery.  Any reason you can't use jquery or another framework?  Your life would be so much easier.

```
var tags = document.getElementsByName('tags');
for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; ++i)
{
    if(tags[i].checked) .....
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need Checkboxes?
Wouldn't this be a great opportunity to use [Radiobuttons](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio)?

Answer (score 2):

You want radio buttons.

```
<input type='radio' name='tags' value='[whatever]' />
```

You won't have to 'check and make sure only one is selected'. And to get the

```
var tags = document.getElementsByName('tags'),
    value = '', i = 0;

for( ; i < tags.length; i++ )
{
    if( tags[i].checked ) {
        value = tags[i].value;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't use radio buttons. Depending on what button is pressed multiple selections is allowed.

Answer (score -1):

from the top of my head... if there is only one checkbox selected it might be document.form1.tags is not an array...